# The functions $\{f_n(x) = n\}$ are analytic and each miss the points $-2, -3$. But, they are not a normal family. So what am I missing. Thanks.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Here is a theorem of Montel:

Let $\mathcal{F}$  be a family of analytic functions defined on a domain  $\Omega$ . If there are two fixed complex numbers $a$ and $b$ that are omitted from the range of every $ƒ ∈ \mathcal{F},$ then  $\mathcal{F}$  is a normal family on  $\Omega .$

However, the functions $\{f_n(x) = n\}$ are analytic and each miss the points $-2, -3$.  But, they are not a normal family.  So what am I missing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In the big Montel theorem, and often otherwise, a normal family is a family $\mathcal{F}$ of meromorphic or holomorphic functions, such that every sequence $(f_n)$ of functions in $\mathcal{F}$ has a subsequence that converges uniformly on compact sets to a meromorphic/holomorphic function, **or to the constant function** $z \mapsto \infty$. Your $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to the constant $\infty$.

The point is that one views holomorphic maps to the Riemann sphere, and from that point of view, $\infty$ is as good a constant holomorphic map as any other constant.

However, it would be better to formulate it in the usual way: "a family that misses three points of the sphere is normal", since that removes the artificial special role of the point $\infty$.

Comment: Okay thanks.  My source didn't explain that.