# Is this family normal?

Tags: complex-analysis, normal-families

Suppose that $R$ is a region, $a \in R$ and $\mathcal{F}=\{f \in H(R) : \mbox{$|f(a)|<1$ and $0,1 \notin f(R)$}\}$. Is this family normal? I guess it is, but I fail to find the reasoning behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Montel's normality criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_normality_test) states that a family of holomorphic functions which all omit the same two values, is normal.

In this context, “normality” means that every sequence in $\cal F$ has a subsequence which either

- converges locally uniformly to a holomorphic function, or
- converges locally uniformly to $\infty$.

(See e.g. Daniel's answer at [The functions $\{f_n(x) = n\}$ are analytic and each miss the points $-2, -3$. But, they are not a normal family. So what am I missing. Thanks.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874928/the-functions-f-nx-n-are-analytic-and-each-miss-the-points-2-3-b/874932#874932)).

Your additional criterion $|f(a)| < 1$ for all $f \in \cal F$ ensures that the second case can not occur.

Comment: An addition: Montel's theorem, applied to this situation, easily gives Schottky's theorem.